# How to animate a CIFilter with CoreAnimation in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, core-image

I want to add a filter to a Layer using `CABasicAnimation`. I'd like to animate some properties of this filter. I read from documentation that the `filters` property is animatable, but in the same documentation, it seems to be really hard to find a way to do that!

So, how can I refer to a single filter property from a CABasicAnimation with animationWithKeyPath ?

```
[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"filters._FILTER_._PROPERTY_"];
```

This is a full example just to show you how I'm trying to get it working:

```
//Define the filter
CIFilter *filterOne = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"];
[filterOne setDefaults];

//Attach it to the Layer
self.layer.filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:filterOne];

//HERE THE PROBLEM ---------------------------------------
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"filters.???????.inputIntensity"];
//EOF HERE THE PROBLEM -----------------------------------

//Define the Animation settings
animation.delegate = self;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
animation.duration = 0.3;
...etcetc...
```

Comment: Have you tried simply @"filters.property"? If you have just one filter in the array this could work, as `setValue:forKeyPath` will apply on every element of the array. No idea for multiple filters...

Comment: @amadour the filters is an NSArray. It can't be referenced as it was a single filter object. I'm using the name of the filter at the moment this way: @"filters.CISepiaTone.inputIntensity" but I get some other problems...

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the layer filters property works at all in iOS. There was a discussion about this recently in the Apple Core Animation forum on Apple's site, and an Apple engineer who goes by "Rincewind" posted that the layer filters feature is not implemented for iOS at all.

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/LayerVisProps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006074-SW17) says:

> **iOS Note:** While the CALayer class in iOS exposes the filters property, 
>   Core Image is not  available. Currently the filters available for this 
>   property are undefined.

As far as I know you can only use CI filters by calling them directly and getting back a CIImage as output. You then have to use the CIImage through code.

Comment: As of iOS 6.1, the docs now say: This property is not supported on layers in iOS. So the docs have caught up with the fact that CIFilters are now supported, but you can't attach filters to a layer like you can in Mac OS.